# Unable to build after importing the Facebook Login kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to implement the facebook login through my app. I have dragged a `UIButton` onto my storyboard and named its class as `FBSDKLoginButton`.

```
   [FBSDKLoginButton class];
```

When I try to put this line in my AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`,it throws the following error when I try to build the app:

```
 ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Users/VenMan/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit', framework linker option at /Users/VenMan/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit is not a dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKLoginButton", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can anyone tell me what is the issue that is causing this error?

Comment: When I used the FB stuff, in addition to including the FBFramework, I also had to set the Xcode framework search path, header search path, and library search path to the FB SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to create the button using code instead of storyboard.

I ran into this problem once before (in another SDK). I suspect the problem is that the linker (which is supposed to tell the storyboard that there is a class called `FBSDKLoginButton`) isn't working as intended for the storyboard, and thus when the storyboard is getting compiled it thinks it has an undefined class.

But of course, check your linked libraries in your app settings just to make sure it is correct. If you are unable to make it work even with code, then try reimporting the Facebook SDK, or start with their example project.